# Gulp play sound on error

Tags: audio, runtime-error, gulp, gulp-watch

Anyone know how to have a sound ( like grunt ) when gulp throw a error during compile/watch ?

l need to setup something special for gulp for have this feature ?

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATE:** It should be noted that gulp-util has been deprecated and should not be used.

There is the ubituious [gulp-util plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-util). One of the features that it provides is the "gutil.beep();" function.

in your project's root execute:

```
npm install gulp-util --save-dev
```

then in your `Gulpfile.js`:

```
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
gutil.beep();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can work with `gulp-plumber` which is excellent for handling errors in `gulp streams`.  Setup the `errorHandler` method which will call the `beeper()` method provided by the `NPM library - beeper`

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var beeper = require('beeper'); //https://www.npmjs.com/package/beeper

gulp.task('compile-sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('blob/for/files.scss')
        .pipe(plumber(errorHandler))
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dest/'));
});

function errorHandler(error) {
    // 3 beeps for error
    beeper(3); // https://www.npmjs.com/package/beeper
    return true;
}
```

Now, whenever there is an error in compiling sass, you will get **3 beeps** to notify you that there was an error.

Good Luck.

Comment: That's deprecated.

Comment: @IvanRubinson Here's the article : https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5.  Now its `const beeper = require('beeper');` and then `beeper()`.  Ref: https://www.npmjs.com/package/beeper.  Also, updated the answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install -g gulp-crash-sound
```

Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-crash-sound

Comment: That does not support Windows.